# How to perform Automated Acceptance Testing across the IBus?

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus, specflow

I just startes working at a software company that uses NServiceBus, so I'm learning and loving it.

I was wondering if I could get your 2 cents on my solution for acceptence-testing:
We're using Specflow to specify and run acceptance tests, and since they are still running NServiceBus 3, I haven't checked out the acceptence-testing framework that came with version 4.

What I have done though, is implement a fake IBus that simply registers handlers using reflection on startup, runs everything in one deterministic and synchronous thread, and provides an easy way to retroactively assert events that was raised...

It supports the needs we have so far (in the prototyping fase), but I keep thinking that this problem have been solved before (and probably better).

Anyone out there with experience automating acceptance-tests for systems using NServiceBus (or any other Service Bus conceptually analogue to NServiceBus)?

Comment: We performed something similar at my previous company; stubbing the bus with reflection, then enabling integration tests (including race hazards etc) by queueing message handling in a deterministic single thread.  After leaving, I asked if we could open source the code, to help other companies with similar issues, but they declined.  
It sounds like we might have solved a few more problems than you have so far.  If you are interested in open sourcing your solution, then I will happily share ideas on how to solve various problems as they come up.

Comment: That'd be great - I'll get back on that!

Comment: - we're actually just now switching to NServiceBus 4, and it looks like the in-memory IBus provided might do the trick... I'll be sure to post a solution if I find one, if not, I got the go-ahead to share our current solution on github.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the NServiceBus usergroup thread [discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/particularsoftware/DZovBWJhxP0), it discusses automated acceptance testing option with V4.